# How to use a custom protocol for my data transfer?

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols, ip

Friends,

I am in a real need of information. I want to develop a protocol with some fields in it.After some study over the net I came to the conclusion that I can use HDRINCL to let the kernel know that the headers are defined in the program. But everwhere I saw that they say All the fields in the header of IP and TCP should be defined. Is it that I can use HDRINCL for my protocol to be used ??

Also one more doubt, suppose I want the IP functionality to be use, like fragmentation, by my protocol. The how to make a call the them ?? can I do so ?

Comment: What kind of protocol do you want to develop exactly? What's the goal?

Comment: Sir, sorry for the late reply..I want to develop a protocol only for LAN. I mean to say whenever we would do s file transfer in a LAN, the OS should use my protocol to carry the data instead of TCP and IP. My protocol would provide the combined feature of TCP/IP excluding some header fields which are not required for a LAN. (P.S.==> When I refer LAN in my context, I mean that, it doesnt contain any router or so. It would be just a combination of hosts,switches,bridges,hubs...but no routers)

Comment: The questioner wants to write a replacement for IP. He is either a madman or a genius.

Comment: I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Linux, it sounds like you want to use a socket of family `PF_PACKET` and of type `SOCK_DGRAM` (see [man packet](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet)). These sockets will automatically include the layer 2 Ethernet headers for you, but it will be up to you to specify the rest of the packet above that layer.

Unfortunately, the fragmentation logic used in IP is tied very closely to the IP protocol, as it relies on fields in the IP header in order to do fragmentation and reassembly. If you are in a hurry and do not want to worry about fragmentation, you could always limit your packets to be smaller than your MTU. Otherwise, I'd suggest using IP fragmentation as a reference point for developing your own fragmentation.

Comment: but SOCK_STREAM socket will indicate that it will be a connection oriented socket and ultimately it will use TCP and IP, am I right ?? Actually I want to skip TCP and IP.

Comment: Sir,Actually I want my own protocol to run but due to lack of time I cant handle fragmentation which would take place over the network for our data. Hence I thought if there is any way to use the predefined fragmentation codes by IP in the kernel..